# What are things one can do with a custom implementation of a self balancing BST as opposed to a STL implementation?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

For example, I know that I can easily rank each node or get kth order statistics just by augmenting each node with a size value. What other benefits do you get over a language implementation like a C++ STL set?

Comment: What does set have to do with a BST?

Comment: Because it's usually implemented as a red black tree. Also you can't augment it without manually editing the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many advantages to coding up your own BST.

As you mentioned in your answer, you can augment the BST to store extra information in each node that is preserved under rotations.  This can be used to build interval trees, link/cut trees, etc. that otherwise could not be done with the black-box standard containers.

Additionally, writing your own tree lets you change how it does balancing.  For example, if you know you are going to have few insertions and deletions relative to lookups, you could use an AVL tree instead of a red/black tree, since those trees have smaller heights.  If you know for a fact that you are going to have a non-uniform access pattern and just one thread, you could use a splay tree.  Or, if you know that overall runtime is all that matters and want to have multithreaded lookups, you could try writing a scapegoat tree.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you implement your own datastructure, you will have to code it, test that it is correct and also be sure that your implementation is efficient.
This is already taken care in STL components so you would prefer reuse an existing implementation than reinvent the wheel yourself.

Comment: Doesn't this detail the benefits of using a prewritten BST over a custom BST, rather than the other way around?

Comment: @templatetypedef:Hi!Yes.What I am saying is that it is better to reuse a pre-written component

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use. like if you do not want custom changes in predefined stl containers then stl containers are best because it is waste of time for building code which is already build.
but forex if you want to implement Binary tree which takes input by checking character where to insert(left or right) then at that time you have build your own BST code .